# Code not getting executed in Ruby threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have a rake task that uses some threads and now I'm getting to a really strange case...

some code didn't get executed so I started playing with simple puts statements...

Basically I have this:

```
Thread.new do
  puts "hi"
  puts "there"
  [more code]
end
```

These are three consecutive runs of my rake task:

```
$ rake task:execute
hi
there
$ rake task:execute
[nothing!]
$ rake task:execute
hi
```

I tried Ruby 2.0 and 2.1.

I don't know if the problem is just in puts but I think not because the code didn't get executed and that's why I started debugging with printouts only to discover that even this doesn't get executed (always).

Strange?

Comment: What may be happening is that the main thread (your main line rake task code) is completing before the sub-thread completes and aborts it. Try doing `t = Thread.new...` (assign your thread to `t`) then do `t.join` at the end of your rake task to give the thread time to catch up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the reference to all the threads and then call join on each of them to wait for them to complete. Ruby will not wait for other threads once the main thread exits.

```
threads = 3.times.map { Thread.new { puts "hello" } }
# do something else while threads run, if you want
threads.each(&:join)
```

Comment: oh I completelly forgot about that..... tnx... before I always had some other code running after starting the threads and this didn't happen,

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread (the rake task itself) is probably completing before your subthread completes. You can do something like this:

```
t = Thread.new do
  puts "hi"
  puts "there"
  [more code]
end

[do other stuff in the main thread]

t.join  # Let the subthread catch up
```